# hibernate hql how to get matched child from parent?

Tags: hibernate

two tables, Cat and kitten(one to many), there are 5 records in the kitten table, and 1 in the cat table. kitten have color, 2 in white and 3 in yellow. I wrote the following HQL which return the Cat.

```
select c from Cat c inner join c.kitten k where k.color='yellow'
```

this return me the cat. but when I did

```
cat.getKitten().size()
```

it returns 5, instead of 3. what I want to do is only get the matched child instead of all of them, what's the right way to do this?

seems like this do the trick, thanks zzz and everyone's effort

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Object> funds = session.createQuery("select k.cat,k from kitten k where k.color='yellow'").list();
        Object[] os = (Object[])funds.get(0);
        Cat c = (Cat)os[0];
        Kitten fc = (Kitten)os[1];
        List list = new ArrayList<Kitten>();
        list.add(fc);
        c.setKittens(list);
```

this return the right thing.

Comment: what does the method getKitten() do??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

btw that is by design. You can't filter a collection by using a restriction.

If you look closer, hibernate is going to the DB twice: once with your query, and once to get the collection.

you need to get your cat object first and then get the filtered kittens which will be lazyloaded by default.

something like

```
var kittens= cat.kittens.where(x->x.color="yellow")
var count=kittens.Count();
```

if java you could do something like this

```
Collection<Kitten> kittens= cat.getKittens();
Collection<Kitten> filteredKittens = filterCollection(kittens, session);
```

and your filterCollection method will be:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> filterCollection(Collection<T> collection, Session s) {
        Query filterQuery = s.createFilter(collection, "where this.color='yellow'");
        return filterQuery.list();
    }
```

here is a blogpost  abt it: http://www.flexpasta.com/index.php/2009/05/20/filtering-hibernate-child-collections/

based on the comments below we decided to use

```
select g, k from grandCat g inner join fetch g.cat c inner join fetch c.kitten k where k.color ='yellow'
```

and select the required content and then cast it appropriatelty.. read the comments for clarity

Comment: The post is tagged hibernate, not nhibernate.

Comment: hmm, do yo know how to do this in hibernate?

Comment: which language do you use? java or c#?

Comment: thanks, but if I have one more layer say GrandCat, which is one to many to the cat. if in the query I already have the grandCat, if I want to get all the cat with yellow kitten and  belong to this grand cat, i have to filter on the cat, then when I want to get the kitten, I have to filter on the kitten. seems a little tedious. because I already have the grandcat, cat and kitten if I use the query select g from grandCat g inner join fetch g.cat c inner join fetch c.kitten k where k.color ='yellow'.

Comment: just try to figure out a best solution.

Comment: in that case you should still select your kittens as follows:
select k from grandCat g inner join fetch g.cat c inner join fetch c.kitten k where k.color ='yellow'.

Comment: and if you really want to select grandcat too you could select both.. edit the select to be select g,k the only difference would be in this case you cant do a list<kitten> or list<cat> it will be a list<object> and then dynamically cast the lists first object to cat and 2nd object to list<kitten>.. hope that made snese

Comment: let me try it and get back to you

Comment: thanks, it works, I post the code as another answer. one more question, when use hibernate load some thing from database to contruct a structure like grandParent--> parent-->child (all one to many) and the contrain is happening on all level, say grandParent.age>100 and parent.name ="abc" and child.color='yellow', the structure is construct by using one hql or more normally get the grandparent first, then query the parent then the child? maybe you can point me a good example? most of the tutorial is just too simple and not that useful.

Comment: make it part of the sma equery and select whatever you want and want to deal with.. make sure you mark this as the answer..

Comment: ok, so you mean use the object[] and then cast it is more common, just like what I did in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you don't want to select the cat, but want to select some of its kittens:

```
select k from Cat c inner join c.kitten k where k.color = 'yellow'
```

This will select 3 kitten, each having the same cat.

Comment: while, in fact this is just a small part of a real case. let's say we have one more layer, GrandCat. GrandCat has cat(one to many) and cat has kitten(one to many). cat has a name property, I want to build the structure so I can do something like grandCat.getCat().get(0).getKitten(); when I query say return the grandCat which has cat name "John" and the kitten has color yellow. if there is not such kitten match, it still return me the GrandCat to Cat to kitten structure, and the cat(john) has an empty list. in this case query the kitten return empty list and no association.

Answer (score 0):

The query asks for all the cats with yellow kittens, but once you have the cat, you are then asking for all its associated kittens (not just the yellow ones).

We might be able to help you more if you show how you have mapped/annotated the Cat/Kitten classes.

Comment: @Nan It depends, do you want:
1. just the yellow kittens
2. the set of cats with yellow kittens where getKitten() returns only the yellow kittens?

Comment: so in this case, after I get the cat, how do I get the only the yellow cat? I am hoping depends on my query, the color on the kitten, the list of kitten will be either 2(white), or 3(yellow) or all 5. query from the kitten side is not applicable, because I cam trying to return a cat anyway, if there is no such kitten has the color, just return me the empty list.