# hibernate what is the right way to load object graph

Tags: hibernate

suppose I have 3 tables GrandCat, Cat, and Kitt. they have the one to many relation so I have the following classes. all association is lazy loading.

```
GrandCat{
    int age;
    Set<Cat> cats;
} 

Cat{
   int age;
   Set<kitt> kitten;
   GrandCat grandCat;
}

Kit{
   String color;
   Cat cat;  
}
```

I want to build a list of grandCat. condition is the grandCat.age > 10 and Cat.age>5 and has at least one kitt which color is yellow. and when I do grandCat.getCats(), only the cats satisfy the condition returns. for example, I have the following cats.
relation like this

```
 grand 1(age>10)--> alex(age>5) ---> a(yellow),b,c             |
                |
                --> bob(age<5)  --->d,e(yellow)

 grand 2(age>10)  --> charlie(age<5) ---> f,g(yellow)
                   |
                   --> david(age>5)--->h
                   |
                   -->edward(age>5)-->j(yellow)
                   |
                   -->fay(age>5) --> i(yellow),k(yellow)

 other grandCats........
```

I want to have the return GrandCats are grand 1 and grand2 like this

```
   grand1-->alex-->a
   grand2-->edward-->j
          |
          -->fay-->i,k
```

they are millons of grandcat, cat, and kitten, so don't want to load them then filter.

I know I can achieve it by using

```
select g,c,k from grandCat g inner join fetch g.cat c inner join fetch c.kitten k where g.age>10 and c.age>5 and k.color='yellow'.
```

and then loop the return value to see which cat belong to which grandCat and kitten to the cat. but this have some drawback, there are duplicates on grandcat and cat level. because they returned as

```
  grand1-->alex-->a
  grand2-->edward-->j
  grand2-->fay-->i        
  grand2-->fay-->k
```

so I need to compare them and filter, when there are many records, this take time and consume resources. 
anyone has a good way to load this? should I use 3 hql? first get matched grandCat1 and grand2

```
select g from grandCat g inner join fetch g.cat c inner join fetch c.kitten k where g.age>10 and c.age>5 and k.color='yellow'.
```

then query the cat using the grandcat return from last query and then put the cat to grand.setcats()

```
select c from Cat c inner join fetch cat.grandCat g inner join fetch c.kitten k where g=:grandCat and c.age>5 and k.color='yellow'
```

then query the kitten and do the same thing?

```
select k from Kitt k inner join fetch k.cat c where c=:cat and k.color='yellow'
```

it seems tedious.

what is the best way to do this? by the way, I hope the returned grandCat and its' cat and kitten still have the lazy loading capability,say if kitten has some other assocation, I can use them in a later time by lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct g from GrandCat g 
inner join fetch g.cat c 
inner join fetch c.kitten k 
where g.age>10 
and c.age>5 
and k.color='yellow'
```

should do it fine. The returned grandcat will only have the wanted cats in its cats collection, and each cat will only have the wanted kitten in its kitten collection.

Be aware that although Hibernate returns entities, these entities do not reflect the reality of the associations. I would treat them as read-only objects, and not try to modify the associations in any way, because it could have disastrous side effects.

Comment: I belive this will return the satisfied grandCats but when you do grandcat.getCats(), all the cats from this grandcat will return regardless it's less than 5 years old and don't have any yellow kitt

Comment: i asked this a few days ago and really did the test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164606/hibernate-hql-how-to-get-matched-child-from-parent

Comment: You missed the fetch after each join. Try it. If you don't fetch, it applies the where clause, but returns GrandCat instances with a non-loaded lazy-loaded set. When you access the set, it lazy-loads the cats of the grandcat, and loads all of them. If you fetch, it populates the sets from the result of the query. That's why I say that the returned entities don't reflect the reality: the cats set is supposed to hold all the cats of the grandcat, not just the ones satisfying the where clause of a specific query.

Comment: ok, thanks,it works. is that mean I have to do the eager fetch and join the table? 3 millon-records tables join will take something, grandcat, cat and kitt just fake table, but my actual table are pretty big

Comment: Not doing it would force you to do a lot more queries, and would certainly be much less efficient. Make sure you have the appropriate indexes. Of course, if the query, with these parameters, return 1 million records, you're in trouble because it will use a lot of memory.

Comment: and when you say ", these entities do not reflect the reality of the associations. I would treat them as read-only objects, and not try to modify the associations in any way, because it could have disastrous side effects." is that means if have add a new kitten to the cat and try to save it in a later time, it has some side effect? what I am trying to do here is to load the the structure all at once, so if there is no kitten, I still have grandcat and cat. in this case, I can add some kitten to it then save these to database

Comment: This query won't load the cats without any kitten. It's possible, but with a different query. Persisting a new Kit with one of the loaded cats as parent should work, but be careful.

Comment: while, seems this query return me a duplication if I use list instead of set in the GrandCat. is there a way to eliminate this from HQL? I get 4 cats instead of 3, fay shows 2 times in the list.