# hibernate remove duplication from hql

Tags: hibernate

this is a question following
 [hibernate what is the right way to load object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194303/hibernate-what-is-the-right-way-to-load-object-graph)
the answer correctly do the work. but because I can not use set(I need order) and trying to avoid treeSet, I use the list in the GrandCat and Cat class. when I use the query, the cat number is not right, instead of 3, it gives me 4. any good way to eliminate this? it has 2 fay Cat in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct c from Cat as c ....
```

See [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation).

Comment: the query I use returning GrandCat, even the grandCat are distinct and ony 1 returns, the cat number is not right. do you mean I need a seperate query just for cat? in production code, I have about 5 level and query each of them would be very inefficient