# hibernate can use list?? there are duplicates

Tags: hibernate

Can hibernate really use list? I doubt it. here is an example.

GrandParent parent and child, all one-to-many bidirection.(many is the control side)

GrandParent has a list of parent and parent has a list of child. if you write sql like this

```
select distinct g from grandParent g inner join fetch g.parent p inner join fetch p.child c where c.age < 5
```

this will select distinct grandparent. but when you try to get parent using g.getParents(); you will find there are duplicates. this problem is very well explained here and give solutions.
http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html

according to the author, there are 3 solutions:

1. use the @IndexColumn 
   Changed the semantics from bag to list (by adding the @IndexColumn annotation) 
   Make the One-to-Many side of the relation as the owning side (to make Hibernate manage the index automatically).

   drawback: because the one-to-many without inverse, it will generate more sql and hurt performance.

   a varity of this is to have some mid table which has the position coloumn to use as index.(see the link). to me, it's more like a hack to the system.
2. use LAZY fetching.
   if you want to have the grandParent has the matched parent and parent have the matched child, you can not ommit the fetch,so you can not lazy load.  this link have example
   [hibernate what is the right way to load object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194303/hibernate-what-is-the-right-way-to-load-object-graph)
3. use set (I think that's the only good soloution, but order get lost, have to use treeset or linkedHashSet).

so my question is. Does list really usable in hibernate? if I really want to use list, is there a better way?

if this force me to load each level(grandparent first then parent then child) seperately, why do I need hibernate, springjdbc can do this use sql more efficiently. is there really a benefit I can get by using hibernate over the springjdbc?

Answer (score 1):

When using `List<Object>` in hibernate you should use `@IndexedColumn`, this is kind of axiom and is reffered in Hibernate Reference Guide black on white in collection mapping chapter, so I don't understand why author of this blog proposed it as work around.

Regarding the Lazy Loading it has a lot of pros and cons if you are using HQL it will not give you any benefits, but if you want to fetch Parent using

```
Parent parent = session.load(Parent.class,id);
```

and perfrom any operation on List and then use

`session.update(parent);`

this is where your Lazy Loading is useful, because parent is loaded as proxy and no select occurred and List is proxy as well. and the amount of selects is minimal.

the problematic side of Laziness is that when you trying to initiate proxy when your Hibernate session is closed (It happens a lot in web applications) you will receive exception.

Comment: You may use a List without IndexColumn. In this case, Hibernate treats the list as a bag (meaning that the order is not significant). Of course, if order is not important and the list should not have duplicates, using a Set is a better option.

Comment: could you point me where the @IndexedColumn is used in the doc. I search the 3.6 and not see it. when you say: if you are using HQL it will not give you any benefits. I don't quite understand. seems it will still lazy loading other associatioin. but my point is, is you do the HQL without a fetch, you will get wrong result. you will get all the parent element of the grandparent, not only the matched one(child.age<5).

Comment: JB Nizet, I am looking for you!! can you take a look at this. I put a comment after you answer. thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194303/hibernate-what-is-the-right-way-to-load-object-graph

Comment: my problem is I need order the parent and the child. so trying to avoid use any kind of set. and when I use list and do the query. it give me the duplicates.

Comment: when I use the indexColumn, and still try to use the many side as control side, it's not working